# Mute and unmute button? (Still needs an answer)

Tags: java, android, audio, service, nullpointerexception

I have been stuck on this for over an hour now. In my main menu screen, I have a mute button. I want it to call a method in my background service, which mutes all of the `MediaPlayer` audio.

Here I am calling mute:

```
    public void mute(View view){
    mutebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mutebutton);

    currentVolume = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    if (currentVolume == 0) {
        TwentySeconds.unMute();
        Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        TwentySeconds.mute();
        Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Here are the methods in the service:

```
public static void mute(){
    ten.setVolume(0, 0);
    three.setVolume(0, 0);
}

public static void unMute(){
    ten.setVolume(1, 1);
    three.setVolume(1, 1);
}
```

Here are the actual media players, which play at intervals:

```
 static `MediaPlayer` ten;
static `MediaPlayer` three;
```

The problem is, I am getting a null pointer exception here:

```
currentVolume = manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

By the way, manager is instantiated like so:

```
 AudioManager manager;
```

and later on:

```
manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

I would really appreciate any feedback (positive or negative)! Thank you so much for all of your help, let me know if you need any more code.

```
 {Rich}
```

Comment: Would it, by any chance, `mute()` was called before `manager` can initialize?  May be show us the whole class (only relevant bits can do) can helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Your "manager" should instantiated like this:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

If this is still a nullpoint, add

```
Context context = this;
```

before your instantiation. Try it, wish I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Grace! I am still getting the nullpointer exception though...?

Comment: Ah...I'm sorry, I didn't see you have wrote "manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);" in the end. Sorry!

Comment: Thats all right, I still appreciate your answer. Do you know what the issue could be then?

Comment: Because my instantiation is actually inside of a countdown timer, I get the following:

Comment: Incompatible types: Required: android.content.Context Found: android.os.CountDownTimer

Comment: This caused me to put the instantiation in the onStartCommand(), but still getting nullpointerexceptions

Comment: I really appreciate your help, please let me know what else to do!

Comment: ...You should get your outmost activity to instantiate context like this: context=xxxactivity.this;